# Can entities share the same material?

Tags: aframe

I have multiple entities which I would like to share the same material. Therefore, if I make a change to the material properties, the properties would be updated on all the entities within the scene using that material.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Create a material manually and attach to mesh:

```
var material = new THREE.SomeMaterial();

AFRAME.registerComponent('my-material', {
  this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material = material;  
});

<a-entity geometry my-material></a-entity>
```

And then you can manually manipulate the material whenever you want and it will auto-apply to all entities / meshes using it (e.g., `material.color.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`).

The mixin method also works although slightly less efficient and more abstracted

Comment: Thanks. My problem with this approach is that an attributes set on "my-material" would be unmanageable. Is there way in which this could be done as an `<a-asset-item>`? The docs imply that with: "<a-asset-item> Miscellaneous assets such as 3D models and **materials**" . Although, I did wonder if 'materials' was a typo for 'texture'.

Comment: You can still add textures. Material component just handles it for you. So like `map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(texture)`.

Comment: My point was that <a-asset-item> doesn't support materials; this is contrary to what the docs say.

Answer (score 1):

Use `a-mixin` with a material component and manipulate its attributes. All entities that have it applied will update:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/mixins.html#sidebar

Comment: Nice, I completely missed that. Do you know if entities will share the same material objects or a new material will be instanced?